# Template engine for header & footer

Tags: html, templates

I'm looking for a simple template engine that allows me to create snippets
for the header, footer etc.

Can anyone guide me on how to start here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your referring to partials, there are **countless** libraries and frameworks that supply this functionality, here are just some of them...

- **EJS** - This is now no longer maintained however it's functionality is still perfect as it comes, provides a simple partial engine and data visualisation.
- **Handlebars** - Oh how so many frameworks use this library, fantastic bit of kit, however this has greater power than just simply loading other files.
- **AJAX** - You can just load a basic HTML file via JQuery .load instead as per the documentation like this...

  $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );

Additionally any respected front-end framework will usually come packed with an engine to load partials with ease.

When you make your partials, be sure to prefix them with an underscore, this is good practice to allow other developers to recognize partials.